# Binomial and Geometric Variables- Finding expected values and variance

Tags: statistics

Suppose $X$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $(100, 1/3)$ and $Y$ is a geometric random variable with parameter 1/4.

(a) Find $E[(50 + X)^2]$.

(b) Find $Var(10 − 2Y )$.

a) I know that for a binomial random variable $E(X)=np$ and in this case $(n,p)=(100,1/3)$ so $E(X)=100/3$ from here though, I am unsure how to manipulate this to achieve the operations that are asked in the question ie. How do i go from $E(X)=100/3$ and use this to get $E[(50 + X)^2]$?

b) For a geometric random variable I know that  $E(Y)=1/p$ and in this case $p=1/4$. From here i know i need to use this to calculate the variance ie. $E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2$ but again, I dont know how to perform the operations asked in the part b) ie. if I have $var(Y)$ how do i transform this into $Var(10 − 2Y )$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) You may already know that the variance of $X$ is $np(1-p)$, that is, $(100)(1/3)(2/3)$.

To find the expectation of $(50+X)^2$, expand the square, and use the linearity of expectation. We get $E(2500)+100E(X)+E(X^2)$.

To find $E(X^2)$, use the fact that $\text{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$.

b) You may already know the variance of a geometric. If you don't, you can derive it or look it up, please see Wikipedia, *geometric distribution*.
In the notation of the OP, it is $\frac{1-p}{p^2}$.

To finish, use the fact that in general the variance of the random variable $a+bY$ is $b^2$ times the variance of $Y$.

Comment: thank you very much! clear and concise

Comment: You are welcome.